# "Orphaned Records" in SQL Server Table

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

We have a SQL Server in Azure and when we run a `SELECT count(*) FROM Table` we get a certain number of results - eg 10.

Listing all the records through a `SELECT * FROM Table` we get the same number of rows returned.

When running a query on .NET Core `.GetAll()`, we get over 1000 records returned. Inserting a record manually to the end of this table, gives an Id of over 3000.

`DELETE FROM Table WHERE Id > 10` never completes, even `WHERE Id > 3000` if the Record Id is 3001, never completes.

Checking the physical stats on the table using both the properties of the index within SSMS as well as running dm_db_index_physical_stats shows no ghost records, but over 1000 Leaf Level Rows, which correlates to what we're seeing with our .NET Query.

I've been waiting on this command to complete for 15 minutes:

```
ALTER INDEX PK_Table ON Table REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = ON)
```

So questions:

1. Why is this data now inaccessible to be seen even through a SELECT() but is showing up in our .NET Query as well as the leaf-level count?
2. What would we call these records? I would call them Ghost or Orphaned records, but SQL Server uses this terminology for different purposes.
3. How do we resolve this issue that we can either clear the corrupt/unreferenced data and rebuild the index, or gain access to the data so we can perform a manual clearup?

I would really like to avoid having to recreate the table and copy the data across.

Answer (score 3):

Azure SQL Database uses a row-versioning-based concurrency model by default.  If your .NET app has inserted rows in an uncommitted transaction, it would not block other sessions from querying the table, but the uncommitted rows would not be visible.

You can read the uncommitted rows with a NOLOCK hint, and examine the other sessions' transactions and with DMVs.

> I've been waiting on this command to complete for 15 minutes:

An uncommitted transaction would also block the ALTER INDEX.  Examine the blocking with

```
select * 
from sys.dm_tran_locks
```

Comment: Thanks David. Fantastic answer. 1,300,998 records in dm_tran_locks Just need to work out who they're from, when they were made and how to clear them!

Comment: KILL XX (where XX is the Session Id) was the easy one. :-)